# module-path in golang for submodules

Tags: go, go-modules

What should I use as module-path when initializing a submodule with command "go mod init [module-path]". Lets say, my project is structured like this:

[image]

Assume the root module (example/go.mod) is initiated with "github.com/example" as the module path. When creating module A, should I initialize it with "github.com/example/A" or "github.com/A" is fine? What's the difference between these two apart from VCS url? If using the first one as the module path, How is it different from the case where there is no go.mod in directory A and we only have a root module?

Comment: Avoid nested modules. Have a top-level module (example), or two modules (A and B).